# Parsing multi-dimensional array with json_decode

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to show the top voters of the month on my website but I'm having trouble with this array:

```
{
   "name":"Server name",
   "address":"***********",
   "port":"****",
   "month":"201601",
   "voters":[
      {
         "nickname":"John",
         "votes":"6"
      },
      {
         "nickname":"Beth",
         "votes":"4"
      },
      {
         "nickname":"Jimmy",
         "votes":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is what I have but it's not working:

```
foreach($results as $nickname => $votes) {
    $i++;

    echo $i . '. ' . $nickname . ' (' . $votes . ')<br \>';
}
```

How would I go by doing this so it shows up like this?

1. John (6)
2. Beth (4)
3. Jimmy (4)

Thank you.

Update: Wow, thank you guys! You were all extremely helpful. It was hard to choose an answer between them all. You're all awesome!

Comment: `foreach($results['voters'] as $voter) {echo $voter['nickname'] . '(' . $voter['votes'] . ')'` ?

Comment: What is `results`? Have you `var_dump`ed them?

Comment: `var_dump($results)` and follow the bracketing...

Comment: what does the variable `$results` hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the data structure, then operate on it as you would any other PHP variables/objects/arrays.

```
<?php
// Raw JSON input
$input = '{
   "name":"Server name",
   "address":"***********",
   "port":"****",
   "month":"201601",
   "voters":[
      {
         "nickname":"John",
         "votes":"6"
      },
      {
         "nickname":"Beth",
         "votes":"4"
      },
      {
         "nickname":"Jimmy",
         "votes":"4"
      }
   ]
}';

//Unserialize the JSON into PHP structures
$results = json_decode($input);

//$results is now an object with properties `name`, `address`, ..., `voters`, etc

// `$results->voters` is an indexed array of objects
// each of these objects have a `nickname` and `votes` property
// no need for a counter, use the index (gleaned from @trincot's answer)
foreach ($results->voters as $i => $voter) {
    // I like `printf` here bcause it keeps my template cleaner to understand
    printf(
        '%s. %s (%s)<br />',
        ($i + 1),
        $voter->nickname,
        $voter->votes
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. It also taught me a little about printf. I did a little research and I'm definitely going to use it more. It does look a lot nicer!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
$i=1;
foreach($result as $r)
{
    echo $i . '. ' . $r['nickname'] . ' (' . $r['votes'] . ')<br \>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with this loop:

```
foreach ($results->voters as $i => $el) {
    echo ($i+1) . ". {$el->nickname} ({$el->votes})<br/>";
}
```

Note that you need first to select the *voters* key, as you are not interested in the other keys at the top level.

Secondly, you're input has some objects (not arrays), so you need to use the `->` operator to access the object properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
$string = '{"name":"Server         name","address":"***********","port":"****","month":"201601","voters":[{"nickname":"John","votes":"6"},{"nickname":"Beth","votes":"4"},{"nickname":"Jimmy","votes":"4"}]}';

$result = json_decode($string);

// To print HTML using DOM
echo "<ol>";
foreach($result->voters as $voter){
    echo "<li>$voter->nickname ($voter->votes)</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```

Working here -> https://eval.in/507711

This code print this HTML

```
<ol><li>John (6)</li><li>Beth (4)</li><li>Jimmy (4)</li></ol>
```

The result is here -> https://jsfiddle.net/h6q8zy86/